# Update UI from a SignalR call

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I am trying to update my UI when I receive a call from the SignalR server.

In my sample code I have two Div tags, which in turn are controlled by different Angular controllers. I have a SignalR service that I have injected into one controller. On receiving event from the SignalR service the first controller broadcasts a message and the second controller is listening to it. 
It should update the UI, but its not doing so...

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my AngularJS & HTML code:

```js
'use strict'

var testapp = angular.module('testapp', []);

testapp.factory('testService',
  function() {
    return {
      testvariable: 0
    };
  });

testapp.service('signalRService',
  function($rootScope, $scope, testService) {

    var myChatHubProxy = null;
    var connection = null;

    var initialize = function() {

      //my signalr server resides here
      connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:28014");

      //creating a proxy
      myChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('myChatHub');

      //Publishing an event when server pushes a greeting message
      myChatHubProxy.on('addMessage', function(message) {
        console.info('Message received from signalr server.');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('MsgFromSRServer');
      });

      connection.start()
        .done(function() {
          console.log('SignalR now connected. Connection Id: ' + connection.id);
        })
        .fail(function() {
          console.log('Could not connect!');
        });
    };

    initialize();

    return {
      initialize: initialize
    };
  });

testapp.controller('SimpleController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'testService', 'signalRService',
  function($rootScope, $scope, testService, signalRService) {

    $scope.makechanges = function() {
      testService.testvariable++;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('MsgFromButtonClick');
    };
  }
]);

testapp.controller('SecondController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'testService',
  function($rootScope, $scope, testService) {

    $rootScope.$on('MsgFromButtonClick', function() {
      $scope.testvar = testService.testvariable;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('MsgFromSRServer', function() {
      testService.testvariable++;
      $scope.updateuimanually();
    });

    $scope.updateuimanually = function() {
      $scope.manualvar = testService.testvariable;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="testapp">
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS - SignalR Sample.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="SimpleController" style="background-color: #c1c1a1; width: 50%; float: left; height: 200px;">
        
            <br />
            <br />

            <button ng-click="makechanges()">Make Change in Second Controller</button>            

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

        </div>
        
        
        <div ng-controller="SecondController" style="background-color: #a1b1c1; width: 49%; float: right; height: 200px;">
            
            <br />
            
            
            <h3>{{ testvar }}</h3>
            
            <button ng-click="updateuimanually()">Update Manually</button>

            <h3>{{ manualvar }}</h3>

            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
       
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="datacontainer2.js"></script> <!-- my angular file -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it able to connect to your signalR service, etc ? What's the actual error happening

Comment: Yes it connects to my SignalR service very well... and thats the problem ... nothing happens ... when I receive a message from the SignalR server it should show an updated variable on the 2nd controller...

Comment: Try this within your addMessage function : `$scope.$apply(function () { $rootScope.$broadcast('MsgFromSRServer');  });` I *think* that might be the issue?

Comment: I did try that but then the page starts throwing an error "Unknown provider: $scopeProvider" etc...

Comment: does `$rootScope.apply` do the trick then?>

Comment: Because I forgot, only controllers & directives have access to `$scope` you can take that injection out of there

Comment: Yup!! that did it ... I removed the $scope from injection ... and instead of $scope.apply used $rootScope.$apply(function () { $rootScope.$broadcast('MsgFromSRServer'); }); and now its working just fine .... Thanks for the help buddy :) ... Please write your comment as an answer so that I can mark this as an acceptable solution to the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: `$scope` is only accessible within controllers & directives.*

In your case here, signalRs callback event doesn't register within the angularJS `$digest` loop (it's not aware anything has changed, or that it needs to look for changes). You need to call it manually (with `$rootScope.apply()`).

```
$rootScope.apply(function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('MsgFromSRServer');
});
```